# Why is this CngKey being imported? (Diffie-Hellman (ECDH) algorithm)

Tags: c#, algorithm, cryptography, diffie-hellman

I am looking at the example provided by Microsoft found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.ecdiffiehellmancng(v=vs.110).aspx#code-snippet-2) for the Diffie-Hellman (ECDH) algorithm implementation.

Why are they assigning a value to unused variable `k`?

```
        using (ECDiffieHellmanCng alice = new ECDiffieHellmanCng())
        {
            alice.KeyDerivationFunction = ECDiffieHellmanKeyDerivationFunction.Hash;
            alice.HashAlgorithm = CngAlgorithm.Sha256;
            alicePublicKey = alice.PublicKey.ToByteArray();
            Bob bob = new Bob();
            CngKey k = CngKey.Import(bob.bobPublicKey, CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPublicBlob);
            byte[] aliceKey = alice.DeriveKeyMaterial(CngKey.Import(bob.bobPublicKey, CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPublicBlob));
            byte[] encryptedMessage = null;
            byte[] iv = null;
            Send(aliceKey, "Secret message", out encryptedMessage, out iv);
            bob.Receive(encryptedMessage, iv);
        }
```

Is there a reason why they are doing this? Did they just forget to use it in the next line?

Comment: I guess so, it seems to have the same value as `bob.bobPublicKey`, which doesn't seem to be explicitly set (usually Bob is a separate entity, and the fields of Bob should therefore not directly be available to Alice, I guess that's where they went wrong).